# Extract numerical values from the String type rows from a column

Tags: python, mysql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

My Requirement is I have a column which consists of below rows.

[image]

I want to extract only the values(numerical) which starts with $ (Ex- 1620.00 and 4,440.00) and also values which are ended with % (Ex- 100, 25, 50) and I want to store these values in a new column with corresponding numerical values , and if a row contains multiple numerical values then I want to create unique columns for each numerical values.

How can we achieve this using Pyspark , or Spark SQL ?

Kindly Help,
Thanks

Comment: Can anyone help to get atleast the numeric values after the $ symbol and numeric values before the % symbol using Python or SQL,  Ex - From above data 100%, I need 100 and for $4,440.00 , I need only 4,440.00

Answer (score 1):

You can transform the text to array using split function, then filter the values that starts with '$' in a new column and the  values that starts with '%' in another, here's an example code:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

data = [
    ["Hello is  $1620.00 per hello;"],
    ["Hello is recalculated to be 15% of item."],
    ["Hello is a case rate of $4,440.00 for up to 3 days etc"],
    ["For multiple services allow 100% of the first item of item, 50% of the second item of item 25% of the 3rd item code 25% of the 4th item"],
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF("text")

result = df.withColumn("splitted_text", split(col("text"), " ")).withColumn("dollars", expr("filter(splitted_text, x -> x like '$%')")) \
    .withColumn("percentage", expr("filter(splitted_text, x -> x like '%\\%')")).drop("splitted_text")
result.show(truncate=False)

+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+
|                text|    dollars|          percentage|
+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+
|Hello is  $1620.0...| [$1620.00]|                  []|
|Hello is recalcul...|         []|               [15%]|
|Hello is a case r...|[$4,440.00]|                  []|
|For multiple serv...|         []|[100%, 50%, 25%, ...|
+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+
```